# Whether to italicise the name of government program in APA style?

Tags: writing, reference-request

I am writing a paper in APA about a government funded program. Do I italicize the name of the program?

Answer (score 3):

APA requires the use of italics for:

- Titles of books, journals and periodicals, films, and videos
- Introduction of new key technical term or label
- Anchors of scale
- Words, phrases, or letters presented as linguistic examples
- General/scientific names, species, and varieties
- Letters in statistical symbols or algebraic variables
- When a reader might not see the intended emphasis or misinterpret the use of a word in a sentence.

The name of a government funded program does not belong into any of these categories. **So the answer to your question is no**.

For sake of completenes, here is when APA forbids the use of italics:

- Emphasis
- Foreign phrases common in English
- Greek letters
- Nonstatistical subscripts to statistical symbols
- Chemical terms

By the way, I found this [information](http://writingcenter.waldenu.edu/1076.htm) simply by googling for "[APA italics](https://www.google.de/search?q=apa%20italics)".

Comment: APA allows authors some _flexibility_ in using italics for emphasis. I certainly support that and have used it, based on my judgement and context at hand. +1